# Looping through python array to match multiple conditions from second array, fast method?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, numpy

I'm a bit of a beginner with Python and want to know if there's a faster way to do this code, so please excuse my ignorance. I have 2 excel sheets: one (*results*) has the about 30,000 rows of unique user ids and I have then 30 columns of questions asked and the cells below those are empty. My second sheet (*answers*), has about 400,000 rows and 3 columns. The first column has the user ids, second has the question asked and third has the answers to each corresponding question from the user. What I want to do is essentially an index-match-array excel function, where I can fill in the blank cells from sheet 1 with the answers from sheet 2 by matching the user id and question asked.

[image: Results sheet]
[image: Answers sheet]

Now I wrote a piece of code, but it took about 2 hours to just process 4 columns from sheet 1. I'm trying to figure out if my way of doing it is not taking complete advantage of the Numpy functionality.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Need to take in data from 'answers' and merge it into the 'results' data
# Will requiring matching the data based on 'id' in column 1 of 'answers' and the
# 'question' in column 2 of 'answers'
results = pd.read_excel("/Users/data.xlsx", 'Results')
answers = pd.read_excel("/Users/data.xlsx", 'Answers')

answers_array = np.array(answers) #########

# Create a list of questions being asked that will be matched to column 2 in answers. 
# Just getting all the questions I want
column_headers = list(results.columns)
formula_headers = []              #########
for header in column_headers:
   formula_headers.append(header)
del formula_headers[0:13]

# Create an empty array with ids in which the 'merged' data will be fed into
pre_ids = np.array(results['Id'])
ids = np.reshape(pre_ids, (pre_ids.shape[0], 1))
ids = ids.astype(str)

zero_array = np.zeros((ids.shape[0], len(formula_headers)))
ids_array = np.hstack((ids, zero_array))    ##########


for header in range(len(formula_headers)):
    question_index = formula_headers[header]
    for user in range(ids_array.shape[0]):
        user_index = ids_array[user, 0]
        location = answers_array[(answers_array[:, 0] == int(user_index)) & (answers_array[:, 1] == question_index)]
        # This location formula is what I feel is messing everything up,
        # or could be because of the nested loops
        # If can't find the user id and question in the answers array
        if location.size == 0:
            ids_array[user][header + 1] = ''
        else:
            row_location_1 = np.where(np.all(answers_array == location[0], axis=1))
            row_location = int(row_location_1[0][0])
            ids_array[user][header + 1] = answers_array[row_location][2]

print ids_array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of populating the first dataframe with the information from second, we can just pivot the second dataframe.

```
answers.set_index(['id', 'question']).answer.unstack()
```

If you needed the rows and columns to be the same as in the `results` dataframe, you can add a `reindex_like` method

```
answers.set_index(['id', 'question']).answer.unstack().reindex_like(results)
```

If you have duplicates

```
cols = ['id', 'question']
answers.drop_duplicates(cols).set_index(cols).answer.unstack()
```

Comment: Hmm problem with that is that column 1 in the answers sheet has duplicate user ids to illustrate their answer for each question

Comment: @MiriamAlh yes, that is why I set index on `id` and `question`

Comment: @MiriamAlh do you have sample data that I can demonstrate with?  Very difficult talking about a data set that I can't see.

Comment: Just edited my question with snippets of sheet examples. I tried your code but I got this error back: **ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape**

Comment: @MiriamAlh that means you have duplicate combinations of id and question in your answers dataframe. Do you expect that?  How do you want to handle duplicates?  Keep first? Last? None?

Comment: Oh I understand the error now (but not sure how to fix it!). The problem with the Results sheet is it has duplicate rows. I'll try to use np.unique to remove them and then try your code again

Comment: Haha yes you said what I just commented :) I just want to take the first since they're exact duplicates including the Responses column

Comment: @MiriamAlh I updated my post. Hopefully that gets you what you need

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you so much